# Create a marquee text GIF

Tags: php, image, text, gif

I know this will take up a lot of bandwidth but I'm willing to do that.

Currently I have a script that will take a number of images and make them into a gif.

And I know how to create a image with text.

I need a function that takes text and scrolls it horizontally from right to left.

Comment: Please take a hint from the other 1.7 million questions on Stack Overflow (well, most of them, anyway) and avoid writing: (a) tags in titles; (b) thanks in posts. Welcome to SO!

Comment: It sounds like you already have the solution. You know how to create each frame, and you know how to join the frames together into an animated GIF. So just go ahead and do it!

Comment: In my opinion there are much better ways of creating a news-ticker style animation, if your intended use is on a web page. Take a look at Javascript tickers, and particularly jQuery plugins which are easy to use and nicer to look at

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop through the x coordinates of the image. Example ($im is your image, text is a function which writes text to $im at the given x,y coordinates):

```
$image_width=imagesx($im);//get width of image
$increment=5;//get increment of text scroll
for($i=0;$i<$image_width;$i+=$increment){//loops the image pixels
text(0,$i);//calls the function text which should draw text to $im at the given coordinates
}
```

Please ask if you don't know how to implement the `text` function.

Answer (score 0):

Although this solution is <s>outdated and universally hated</s> super oldskool, it really does sound like you're actually looking for the html [**`<marquee>`**](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html) tag.

```
<marquee>this text will scroll from right to left!!!</marquee>
```